# How to config Windows Defender Firewall for VSC?

Tags: windows, networking, security, wireless-networking

Installing VSC (Visual Studio Code) on Windows 10 at home. Believe `private` should be checked as I'm at home and private network is more secure than public. Why `public` is checked by default not the other way? How does Windows know the network is Public or Private? For example a coffee shop's wifi may not flag itself as Public, nor a hacker's wifi hotspot at the airport, and my own home network does not broadcast itself as Private.

[Windows Defender Firewall has blocked some features of this app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/viDbq.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How does Windows know the network is Public or Private?

When you first connect to a new network, Windows asks you "Do you allow your PC to be discoverable by other PCs and devices". If you press **No** or ignore it, the network will stay as **Public**. If you select **Yes**, the network will be marked as **Private**. By default all networks are **Public**

You can change the type from **Private** to **Public** and vice versa for your current connection in: `Win + X > Settings > Network & Internet > [Properties] button`

You can check settings differences for **Private** and **Public** networks in: `Win + X > Search > Control Panel > All Control Panel Items > Network and Sharing Center > Advanced sharing settings`

**Domain** network type is set automatically if your computer is joined to Active Directory domain and connected to the corporate network.

> Why public is checked by default not the other way?

By default all networks are Public. So the default would work most of the times.

Comment: Good answer, and how does it know if the network is private or public?

Comment: @Jeb50 I have updated my answer to clarify how Windows knows if it is Public or Private. In short, user marks a network as Private by answering a prompt. Otherwise, all networks are considered Public.